# How customize Yahoo Messager Link images

Tags: html, css

how to customized the image (online/offline) use in Yahoo! Messenger Links.

```
<a href="ymsgr:sendim?UserID"><img src="http://opi.yahoo.com/online?u=USERID&amp;m=g&amp;t=2" border="0" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a server side script request the image. Determine which one it is. Send back the image of your choice.

You can't do this client side (without finding a different Yahoo! API to call) since attempts will be blocked by the same origin policy.

Comment: unfortunate you're correct. there's no other way but to get different Yahoo! API unfortunately I think there is none. :D thanks